# Is it better to negotiate a faculty offer by email or phone?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, negotiation

When negotiating a faculty offer with a search committee chair, is it better to do it via email or phone? Which one is more efficient and can get better results? For example, email have the advantage of written points, while in phone you can sense the other person feedback.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the kind of offer and general circumstances surrounding it.

Comment: A lecturer position in a college

Comment: @ThomasLee A few questions: (a) are you asking the question from the perspective of the applicant or the recruiter? (b) Why is face-to-face not an option? (c) You may wish to provide further context for what is being negotiated or at least what is motivating the question? (i.e., pay, lab startup, level, etc.)

Comment: @JeromyAnglim: "why not face-to-face?" Because it's generally  impractical to do face-to-face negotiations. However, I don't think the question fundamentally changes if we ask "orally or by written means?"

Comment: Better in which respect? And with whom are you negotiating? With some admin person having to decide about your resources or with colleagues in your future department to figure out the teaching allocation?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim both sides, and it is not possible to travel, mainly salary and other associated items.

Comment: @CrepusculeWithNellie speed and efficeincy. With search committee chair.

Comment: @ThomasLee Given the additional information added into the question (lecturer position, search committee chair), I think the question is specific enough to answer and I have voted to reopen.  It would also be useful to know what country (e.g., "lecturer" means something different in the UK and US)

Comment: When in doubt, I'd ask what the other party would prefer. As the supplicant, you want to make yourself as easy to work with as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negotiating the conditions of any future employment is an important conversation.

Most of human communication is non-verbal. We communicate a lot through our voice tone and body language.

Some people avoid face-to-face, or telephone conversations, as they find the interaction awkward. Ask yourself:- if you were the search committee chair, would you want to employ someone as a lecturer who was uncomfortable in face-to-face communication?

At least offer to have a telephone conversation, or Skype, or video conference with the other party, if a face-to-face meeting is impractical or inappropriate. This shows you are keen to engage in the most efficient means of human-to-human communication. Then follow this up with an email clarifying the main points of your conversation.